# How to let `git diff` invoke `git difftool -t opendiff -y`?

Tags: git, git-diff, git-difftool

The short question is: how to make

```
git diff
```

invoke

```
git difftool -t opendiff -y
```

? The second line is to invoke `opendiff` to diff some files, even when there is no configuration whatsoever done beforehand (I am using `git` version 1.9.2 and the current Xcode 12.1 on macOS Catalina and Big Sur).

The line

```
git config --global diff.external 'git difftool -t opendiff -y'
```

does not work.

---

Longer details:

We can readily invoke `opendiff` using `git difftool -t opendiff -y`, so `git` knows how to use `opendiff` as a visual diff tool without any additional configuration. And there is a way on github about [how to use `diff.external` to invoke a separate shell script to invoke `opendiff`](https://gist.github.com/bkeating/329690).

So since `git` readily knows how to invoke `opendiff` using `difftool`, we really should not need to use an external shell script.  For the fact that `diff.external` can invoke any external command, then it would appear logical to even invoke itself, which is to invoke `git difftool -t opendiff -y`, but the line

```
git config --global diff.external 'git difftool -t opendiff -y'
```

won't work and can cause an error when we do a `git diff` afterwards. (it may appear it is due to `git` passing additional arguments to the "external" command?)  The error it gives is:

```
fatal: 234c9c6e7d7f2798068d2f6ee434af9a9dd88123: no such path in the working tree. 
Use 'git <command> -- <path>...' to specify paths that do not exist locally. 
external diff died, stopping at foo.rb.
```

How to make it work so that `git diff` can invoke the `git difftool` with `opendiff`?  It seems `git diff` and `git difftool` is a little bit adhoc, because we even configure the default `difftool` to use using `git config --global diff.tool opendiff` so we are touching `diff` to configure `difftool`. So in a way `git diff` and `git difftool` look like separate things but in a way they look like they are one unit.

One way to make it work but using an alias is

```
git config --global alias.diffy 'difftool -t opendiff -y'
```

but then we will need to use `git diffy` to run it instead of `git diff`. We can also create a Bash or Zsh alias `gitdiff` to run `git difftool -t opendiff -y` but it seems we should be able to use `git diff` without setting up an additional shell script.

Comment: What exactly does "does not work" mean?

Comment: Note that `git difftool` *is* a shell script (with a small front end that does the initial setup). It's not really true that Git knows how to invoke `opendiff`. Instead, `git difftool` simply runs *any arbitrary command* with arguments supplied by the script.

Comment: @mkrieger1 please see the error in the updated details

Comment: @torek isn't `difftool` part of the `git` release?  so you are saying `difftool` is almost the same as using the shell script using `diff.external`...  any way to just make `git diff` use *that* script then, without we building a shell script separately?

Comment: Parts of Git are just shell scripts that cobble together individual tools. Mergetool and difftool are done this way; they build on how Git uses its index. The `git diff` command is fairly different from these: it's a front end that picks one of three different back ends to run (`git diff-tree`, `git diff-index`, or `git diff-files`), and those are the core diff-engine parts of Git. Meanwhile setting an external diff is a way to direct the front end (`git diff`) to run a script: so it's at the same level, as it were, as `git difftool`.

Comment: That's where your existing efforts are bottoming out or running aground or whatever metaphor you prefer. If you write your own script, you must pick one of the lower-level Git tools (diff-index or diff-tree or diff-files) to drive it.

Comment: @torek then it might seem that `git` could use some sort of `diff.difftool` to specify a visual diff too and use it just like `git difftool`

Comment: Well, maybe. You can always make proposals on the Git mailing list, of the form: "here's our usage scenario, here's a proposed change to make it work conveniently, and here's why we think this should be in future Git versions."